# unable to use @AspectJ with Spring-Apache CXF services

Tags: spring, cxf, aspectj

I am new to spring and am working on a rest service written using Spring and Apache CXF with Java Configurations. I have the following rest service.

```
@Path("/release/")
@Component
@RestService
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ReleaseResource extends AbstractService implements IResource {


    @Override
    @CustomLogger
    @GET
    public Response get() {
        //Some Logic
        return Response.ok("Success!!").build();
    }

}
```

I have created an aspect using @AspectJ for logging. However, the aspect is not working on the services written in CXF. I did a bit of searching in net and found that Spring needs proxy beans for the aspects to work. Then I tried few approaches such as

1. Making the service class implement an interface
2. Using CGLIB library and scope proxy mode TARGET_CLASS
3. Extending a class with method

   ```
   @Override
   public void setMessageContext(MessageContext context) {
       this.context = context;
   }
   ```

But none of them worked.
Any idea if it is possible to run the aspect around the services?
If yes, can someone please tell me how to.

I have read that this can be achieved by bytecode weaving the aspectj manually instead of using spring aspectj autoproxy (not sure how to do it though). Can someone tell me if this is a good option and how to do it?

EDIT:

Sorry for the incomplete info provided. Attaching the other classes

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class LoggerAspect {


    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod() {
    }

    @Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(CustomLogger)")
    public Object logAction(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, CustomLogger customLogger) throws Throwable {

        //Log Some Info
        return pjp.proceed();

    }
}
```

Web Initializer class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(createWebAppContext()));
        addApacheCxfServlet(servletContext);

    }

    private void addApacheCxfServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet("CXFServlet", cxfServlet);
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        appServlet.addMapping("/*");
    }

    private WebApplicationContext createWebAppContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(TestConfig.class);

        return appContext;
    }

}
```

Config Class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.package")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class TestConfig {
    private static final String RESOURCES_PACKAGE = "com.my.package";

    @ApplicationPath("/")
    public class JaxRsApiApplication extends Application {
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public SpringBus cxf() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider() {
        return new JacksonJsonProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggerAspect getLoggerAspect() {
        return new LoggerAspect();
    }

    @Bean
    IResource getReleaseResource() {
        return new ReleaseResource();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("cxf")
    public Server jaxRsServer(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createEndpoint(jaxRsApiApplication(),
                JAXRSServerFactoryBean.class);

        factory.setServiceBeans(restServiceList(appContext));
        factory.setProvider(jacksonJsonProvider());

        return factory.create();
    }

    private List<Object> restServiceList(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        return RestServiceBeanScanner.scan(appContext, TestConfig.RESOURCES_PACKAGE);
    }

    @Bean
    public JaxRsApiApplication jaxRsApiApplication() {
        return new JaxRsApiApplication();
    }

}
```

RestServiceBeanScanner class

```
public final class RestServiceBeanScanner {

    private RestServiceBeanScanner() {
    }

    public static List<Object> scan(ApplicationContext applicationContext, String... basePackages) {
        GenericApplicationContext genericAppContext = new GenericApplicationContext();
        ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner scanner = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(genericAppContext, false);

        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(RestService.class));
        scanner.scan(basePackages);
        genericAppContext.setParent(applicationContext);
        genericAppContext.refresh();

        List<Object> restResources = new ArrayList<>(
                genericAppContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(RestService.class).values());

        return restResources;
    }

}
```

Comment: How about sharing your aspect and the Spring configuration? Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: Hi @kriegaex , sorry for the incomplete info. Added the aspect and spring configs. Hope this info is sufficient. :) Thanks.

Comment: `@Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(timed)") public Object logAction(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, CustomLogger customLogger)` will never work because a) you never bind the pointcut expression `@annotation(timed)` to a method parameter and b) method parameter `customLogger` never occurs in your pointcut. I have not even looked at the rest because these two problems already block your progress.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was using @annotation(customLogger) only. And this aspect works completely fine when i autowire an object in which the methods are annotated with @CustomLogger, and then call them from the service class. However it does not work on the web services themselves.

Comment: `@Bean public TimerAspect getLoggerAspect() { return new LoggerAspect(); }` also does not make sense. I repeat: Please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest GitHub because I do not like to keep guessing what might be wrong because of copy & paste errors. It obscures the view onto the real problem.